# CSS Trick's Responsive Data Table (with inline edit mode) display issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, datatable, responsive-design

I am using the guide ([click here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)) written by Chris at CSS-Tricks to create a responsive table. I am also trying to add inline editing to the table.

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQkb7nN0QEKgKdW4IEYp?p=preview)**

- The responsiveness works in mobile-screen mode.
  [image]
- The inline editing works before entering mobile-screen mode.
  [image]
- It all goes down hill when inline editing is enabled in mobile-screen mode.
  [image]

Main CSS:

```
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
}
/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#demoTable td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
}
td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;

    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming because when you edit the code `td` has `col-xs-12` div which have `float:left`, so `td` not getting proper height.

Try this code:

```
@media screen only and (max-width:767px){
   #demoTable td .col.col-xs-12 {
      float: none;
      padding: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)